# Why are the festivals misordered in the movie Baghban?

Tags: plot-explanation, baghban

Amitabh Bachchan and Hema Malini are separated right after Holi (remember Amitabh singing Holi khele Raghubeera?). They are said to be separated for six months, ie from March to September.

Within that six-month period, they celebrate Valentine's Day, which falls on February 14, and karva chauth, which is usually observed in October. There is no way these two occasions could come between March and September!

Answer (score 1):

There is no clarification given by the movie maker about it, but I remember in the story that Karvachoth appears before Valentine, so that means Amitabh Bachchan and Hema Malini are not separated right after Holi (they displayed the Holi scene before their separation, but that doesn't means they separated right after it). And I also remember that there were some scenes between the Holi scene and the separation scene, which means they separated a little bit before October. Correct me if i am wrong.